# Printing a multi dimensional array using one Foreach loop only

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Recently I've been given an interview where many question were ask, but there was one question I could not answer which was the following:

Printing a multi dimensional array using one `foreach` loop only.

```
$cars = array (  
    array("Volvo",22,18), 
    array("BMW",15,13),
    array("Saab",5,2),
    array("Land Rover",17,15) 
);
```

Interviewer asked me to print the above array using only one `foreach` loop. Can anybody give me answer for this?

Comment: Have you tried to print?

Comment: Give us a sample of the multi dimensional array.

Comment: This will be interesting..

Comment: hey, i  have added the array

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive function for this. Only one `foreach` loop calls recursively.

```
$cars = array(array("Volvo",22,18),array("BMW",15,13),array("Saab",5,2),array("Land Rover",17,15));

function displayArr($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            displayArr($value);
            echo "<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo $value . " . ";
        }
    }
}

displayArr($cars);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$cars = array (  array("Volvo",22,18), array("BMW",15,13),array("Saab",5,2), array("Land Rover",17,15) );

foreach($cars as $car) {
    print("Name: ".$car[0]."\n");
    print("Number 1: ".$car[1]."\n");
    print("Number 2: ".$car[2]."\n");
}
```

Obviously could could make checks to see if the other keys in the inner arrays are set. But seems your array will always contains all the keys.

EDIT:

Based on the comment you left you want to be dynamic as possible so do to that you need to use recursion or the goto control structure.

```
$cars = array (  array("Volvo",22,18), array("BMW",15,13),array("Saab",5,2), array("Land Rover",17,15) );

foreach($cars as $car) {
    $count = 0;

    A:
    if(isset($car[$count])) {
        print($car[$count] . "\n");
        $count +=1;
        goto A;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you give indexing to array, if there is thousands of values in array then what, should i write it thousand time to print all values.

Comment: Nope you don't have too am just doing stuff based on the array you provided. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Wow, thats the first time I have seen a `goto` since the 80's. Almost tempted to give you an UV for digging it out of the back of the tool bag, dusting it off and giving it a day in the sunshine

Comment: @RiggsFolly and I wasn't even born then. I guess its the fact I work with seniors around me hehe xD. Not really. It was the first thing I come up and that I was sure would work with out testing it.

Comment: @Andre Ferraz thank you for answer and yes you are right  i wanted the dynamic foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cars = array (
    array("Volvo",22,18), 
    array("BMW",15,13),
    array("Saab",5,2),
    array("Land Rover",17,15) 
);

foreach($cars as $car){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($car);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: This is extremely vague, could you provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

This can give you the result.

```
<?php
$cars = array (  array("Volvo",22,18), array("BMW",15,13),array("Saab",5,2), array("Land Rover",17,15) );

array_map('fun', $cars);
function fun($cars){
    foreach($cars as $car){
        echo $car."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

output

```
Volvo 22 18 BMW 15 13 Saab 5 2 Land Rover 17 15
```

use array_map to traverse through the child arrays .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that does not use even one `foreach` loop

```
function walk2($item, $key)
{
    echo $key . ' - ' . $item.PHP_EOL;
}

function walk1($car, $key)
{
    array_walk($car, 'walk2');
    echo '------'.PHP_EOL;
}

array_walk($cars, 'walk1');
```

Gives the output :

```
0 - Volvo
1 - 22
2 - 18
------
0 - BMW
1 - 15
2 - 13
------
0 - Saab
1 - 5
2 - 2
------
0 - Land Rover
1 - 17
2 - 15
------
```

Although possibly the question was supposed to make you ask logical questions about the make up of the array so they could test your analytic skill as much as your ability to jump through coding hoops.

Also, even though you are not using a foreach, or any other loop you are making use of the 'C' code that was written for these functions which of course is making use of some sort of loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($cars as $key=>$car){
    echo $car[0];
    echo $car[1];
    echo $car[2];
}
```