# -Iterate through multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array. To output all the values, is there an easier way than looping over each level like I do below?

```
$results['English']['Listening'][] = 100;
$results['English']['Listening'][] = 80;
$results['English']['Exam'][] = 70;
$results['English']['Exam'][] = 90;
$results['Computer']['Exam'][] = 90;

foreach ($results as $subject => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $component => $scores) {
        foreach ($scores as $score) {
            echo "$subject => $component => $score" . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: no easier way to do this, unless you want to restructure your array. :D

Comment: @mutokenji: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453063/2156244

Comment: no other way. @mutokenji